# UIScrollview and Nav bar content offset issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, navbar

So i am trying to get my head around how the nav bar and scroll views can work together.

the issue i am having is when i put my label on a view controller that has a nav bar and scroll view it seems that i must put the label underneath the nav bar so it's obscured by the nav bar in order to get the right amount of offset.

The thing is, if i click on the view controller and change the Top Bar from inferred to None and set up my views that way and then switch it back after my views are set up it seems to work, e.g. it automatically moves my content on the inteface builder to be below the nav bar and all constraints then work ok.

I am guessing i am missing the concept here on how scroll views and nav bars are set up as surly you dont have to change it to none and then back again in order for it to correct the views?

Edit 1: it seems that its to do with where I pin the top of the label.... if I pin it to Top Layout Guide (so it adjusts successfully for the nav bar and status bar) then it doesn't move at all, If I pin it to top of the container view I have then its set at 64pts which I don't want hardcoded?

[image: Scroll View with Label]

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on the Navigation Bar property of `Translucent`
If the Navigation bar is Translucent then content is visible as in the example below. This will need the scroll view to be extended to behind the Navigation Bar

[image: Translucent demo]

If `Translucent` is set to `false` then there is no need for the scroll view to be behind the Navigation Bar hence pushing the scroll view to under the Navigation bar.

Changing from infrared to none causes the view controller to use the navigation bar as a normal element on the screen regardless of its Translucent property.

**Update 1: Implementation**

I think I get what you want to do with the scroll View but why use a container? why not just add the imageViews and Labels directly to the scrollView. I also would suggest a better way to go about this, Why don't you use a tableViewController with a view as its header and without any cells.

[image]
[image]

You can now set a fixed size for the content or change the size programmatically

create an `IBOutlet` from your containerView to your code

in the `viewDidLoad`

```
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: self.tableView.frame.height)
```

or

```
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: 200)
```

or

```
containerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.frame.width, height: self.tableView.frame.height * 2)
```

depending on how you want to config the view. I think this is the easiest way to deal with scrollView using the interface builder.

Comment: Thanks, so how do I go about setting up the interface correctly. At the moment I have a view controller with the nav bar inherited as it segues to this, I put a scroll view on the view controller that goes under nav bar as I want the content to scroll under it so I can see it. I then add a new view onto the scroll view to be used as the container view where I can then add my images and labels to scroll, this view also takes up the whole size. Now when I put a label at the top and pin it, and then run, it seems to display in the incorrect place on the simulator (adding twice the nav bar size)

Comment: added an update to my original, it seems to be where I pin the label? not sure what its top anchor should be